# how can I change the text of the button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I need to change the text of the button after the success adding to the basket. But it change it just after the second click. How can I change it if Im using foreach in php

```
<td>
<?if(count($arElement["OFFERS"]) > 0):?>
    <?foreach ($arElement["OFFERS"] as $offer): ?>
        <?//var_dump($offer["ID"]);?>
        <div class="button456" >
            <button class="button-offer" id="but123" onclick="add2basket(<?=$offer["ID"]?>)">To the basket</button>
    <?endforeach?>

<?else:>
    <button class="button-simple" id="but1234" data-id="12345" onclick="add2basket(<?=$arElement["ID"]?>)">To the basket</button>
<?endif?>
        </div>
</td>
<script type="text/javascript">
function add2basket(ID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax/add_tobasket.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {PRODUCT_ID: ID,QUANTITY: $(".quantity" + ID).val(),},
        success: function (html) {
            $('button').on('click', function(){
                $(this).closest('button').text("In the basket");
            });
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: fyi, you could have multiple duplicate `id` attributes, which is invalid, `id`s need to be unique

Comment: This code generates this error `parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting "elseif" or "else" or "endif"` Probably among others. Do you have Error reporting turned on

Comment: Another fyi: move the `</div>` inside the `foreach`

Comment: @brombeer I try to do unique id like that:$(document).ready(function(){

 $('button#but<?=$arElement["ID"]?>').closest('button').text("In the basket");
}) but ut still not work. How can I do unique id?

Comment: Did you also change all of your `<button>`s `id`s to be unique? Also, that was an fyi, I didn't say this would solve your problem

Comment: @brombeer yes i change <td>
    <?foreach ($arElement["OFFERS"] as $offer): ?>
     <?//var_dump($offer["ID"]);?>
     <div class="button456" >
      <button id="but<?=$offer["ID"]?>" onclick="add2basket(<?=$offer["ID"]?>)">To the basket</button>
      </div>
     <?endforeach?>

     <?else:?>
     <div class="button111">
     <button  id="but<?=$arElement["ID"]?>" onclick="add2basket(<?=$arElement["ID"]?>)">To the basket</button>
    </div>
 $('button#but<?=$offer["ID"]?>').on('click', function(){
     $(this).closest('.button456').text("In the basket");
 });

Comment: @RiggsFolly hi, no i dont have this errors

Comment: DOnt get the error OR **not looking for or showing  the error**

Comment: To fix your "second click only" problem remove the second click function `$('button').on('click', function(){ ... }` so it's only `$(this).closest('button').text("In the basket");` - you already clicked the button, no need to add another event listener there

Comment: @brombeer I try it, but it dont change the text of the button